# how to write back to an existing file, ensuring the bits on the disk get overwritten in OS X

Tags: cocoa, security, filesystems

What API's Cocoa or Core Foundation, can I use to make sure that when I write back to a file that already exists on the storage device, that the bits get written over?  The idea is to clear out the bits for security reasons.

Answer (score 5):

In modern filesystems, there's no way to guarantee that you are overwriting the same physical location on disk -- the *lack* of that guarantee allows the filesystem to offer you better performance.  You might be interested in reading [this paper (PDF)](http://www.monetra.com/docs/security/secure_delete.pdf), appropriately titled ***Why secure delete doesn't work*** and no sensitive data should ever be stored         unencrypted on disk (emphasis mine).

Consider also this warning from [the `shred` manpage](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?shred+1):

> CAUTION:  Note  that  shred relies on a very important assumption: that
>          the file system overwrites data in place.  This is the traditional  way
>          to  do  things, but many modern file system designs do not satisfy this
>          assumption.  The following are examples of file systems on which  shred
>          is not effective, or is not guaranteed to be effective in all file system modes:
>
> - log-structured or journaled file systems, such as those supplied with AIX and Solaris (and JFS, ReiserFS, XFS, Ext3, etc.)
> - file systems  that  write  redundant data and carry on even if some writes fail, such as RAID-based file systems
> - file systems that make snapshots, such  as  Network Appliance's  NFS server
> - file systems that cache in temporary locations, such as NFS version 3 clients
> - compressed file systems

That being said, there *might* be some way within Cocoa or Core Foundation to allow you to write to a specific head/cylinder/sector/etc. on a disk -- I'm not familiar enough with those APIs -- but I highly doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

No such API exists. It would be much better to only store properly encrypted data on disk if you are worried about security.