# Securely delete NSURL file and show percent in NSProgressIndicator

Tags: cocoa

I am trying to create a "document shredder" application for Mac.  I have the NSURL of the files that the user selected, but how would I go about securely deleting said files and passing the progress along to a progress bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look at the posix layer calls for file I/O, with those you can overwrite files and implement any algorithm for secure deletion you choose.

If you just need to securely delete the file and are not concerned over showing progress in a GUI you can invoke the `srm` (secure remove) command using `NSTask`. For details on the `srm` enter `man srm` in a Terminal window.

If you do want to show progress in a GUI then you can convert the output of that command, captured with `NSTask` and display it as you choose. Or Apple provide the source to `srm`, you can find it [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/srm/) on the Apple Open Source site and you can incorporate code/algorithms from that into your own code and provide progress indication in your GUI.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to "securely delete" files from the Cocoa API.

You can use NSFileManager to move files into the trash can, which then leaves it up to the user to delete, or securely delete, the files via the Finder menu.

You could also use NSFileManager to move files into the trash and then use AppleScript to send Finder a message to delete/securely delete files, however, this is generally not a good idea unless your user has specifically requested you empty their trash as you may delete things they are not ready to have deleted.

Otherwise, there does not seem to be an easy or direct way to accomplish a secure delete of files as with the standard API there is no guarantee that the bytes you write out to disk are going to overwrite the ones that existed before.

You may also want to check out this previous question here on SO in relation to why secure delete is not that secure:
[how to write back to an existing file, ensuring the bits on the disk get overwritten in OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529182/how-to-write-back-to-an-existing-file-ensuring-the-bits-on-the-disk-get-overwri)

Comment: I know you can do this via Terminal, the only issue is I'd need to be able to get the live percentage from Terminal somehow.